# What is the best machine learning algorithm to use for predicting number of operations across a year?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, prediction

I have a data frame of two columns, the first is a series of dates and the second is the number of operations done in 2019. I want to apply ML to predict the number of operations in 2020.

I've tried using Sklearn LinearRegression for prediction after converting the dates to 'int64', but the predicted values are too far from what is expected for me and the coef_ is -3

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn import metrics
import datetime
df= pd.read_csv(r'...surgical_clean.csv')
df= pd.to_datetime(df['pd_date_of_operation']).value_counts().to_frame().reset_index()
year_start = np.datetime64(pd.to_datetime(2017, format= '%Y'))
df= df[(df['index'] >= year_start)].astype('int64')
x= df.iloc[:,:-1].values
y= df.iloc[:,1].values
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test= train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0) 
regressor= LinearRegression()
model= regressor.fit(x_train,y_train)  
y_pred= model.predict(x_test).round(0)
>>>array([4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.,
       4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.,
       4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.,
       4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.,
       4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.,
       4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.,
       4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.,
       4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.,
       4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.,
       4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.])
```

```
print(model.coef_)
print(model.intercept_)
>>>[-3.81638905e-18]
9.546358714910848
from sklearn import metrics
print('Mean Absolute Error:', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred).round(1))
print('Mean Squared Error:', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred).round(1))
print('Root Mean Squared Error:', np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)).round(1))
>>>Mean Absolute Error: 1.1
Mean Squared Error: 2.4
Root Mean Squared Error: 1.5
predict = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test, 'Predicted': y_pred})
predict.sum()
>>>Actual       589.0
Predicted    636.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is completely wrong. You use Machine learning to train a model that fits a set of "[features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_(machine_learning))" and it's respective "values" or "[labels](https://medium.com/technology-nineleaps/some-key-machine-learning-definitions-b524eb6cb48)".

In your case, your are treating date as a feature and that is exactly where you went wrong!

**Date is not a feature. Date is not a characteristic of a phenomenon (number of operations).**

Your choice of "value"/"label" is "number of operations". No issues there.

Before you dive into fixing the bugs in code, correct your understanding of Machine learning.

Somethings to consider for this problem statement:

In your dataset, you might have some "variables" (i.e "features") that affect your number of operations like weather. On a rainy day, your number of operations may go down, on a sunny day the operations may be high (I don't know what "operations" you mean, but this is just an example I am giving). So the weather will be a "feature" that you can use in your model training. Now there might be more than one "feature" (maybe even up to a million, that will depend on your dataset).

Find out all the possible features in your dataset and then choose what technique will be right like Linear Regression, Clustering, SVM's and so on.

Happy learning! :)

Comment: Thanks a million. "operation" here means a medical procedure that is done for a patient. The dataset consists of two columns, a date column and the number of operation that were done in this date. The task is to predict how many operations will be done in future dates.

Comment: Sure you can. But that will involve feature engineering of your data: Converting your time series data into supervised learning. While feature engineering you will define "lag times" or "lags" (lag_X, X can be 1,2....). Oncle feature engineering is complete, you can start with time series forecasting. Then there is also the concept of "stationarity" (https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411diff.htm). It is a very interesting topic, do check it out. But applying a linear regression on date/time is not time series forecasting.